# Map dataframe index using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Why doesn't `df.index.map(dict)` work like `df['column_name'].map(dict)`?

Here's a little example of trying to use index.map:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30, 'D': 40, 'E': 50}})
map_dict = {'A': 'every', 'B': 'good', 'C': 'boy', 'D': 'does', 'E': 'fine'}
df
'''
    one
A   10
B   20
C   30
D   40
E   50
'''

df['two'] = df.index.map(mapper=map_dict)
```

This raises `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Feeding it a lambda works:

```
df['two'] = df.index.map(mapper=(lambda x: map_dict[x])); df
'''
   one    two
A   10  every
B   20   good
C   30    boy
D   40   does
E   50   fine
'''
```

However, resetting the index and mapping on a column works as expected without complaint:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index': 'old_ndx'}, inplace=True) #so there's no index name confusion
df['two'] = df.old_ndx.map(map_dict); df

'''
  old_ndx  one    two
0       A   10  every
1       B   20   good
2       C   30    boy
3       D   40   does
4       E   50   fine
'''
```

Comment: According to [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Index.map.html), `pandas.Index.map` requires a callable. Is your question *why* was this design decision made?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12756) is a relevant issue. It seems it's just something that slipped through the cracks, that they haven't gotten around to fixing. It seems that it is [currently being remedied](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15081).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm not answering your question... Just giving you a better work around.
Use `to_series()` them `map`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30, 'D': 40, 'E': 50}})
map_dict = {'A': 'every', 'B': 'good', 'C': 'boy', 'D': 'does', 'E': 'fine'}

df['two'] = df.index.to_series().map(map_dict)

df

   one    two
A   10  every
B   20   good
C   30    boy
D   40   does
E   50   fine
```

Answer (score 23):

Adding `get` at the end

```
df['Two']=df.index.map(map_dict.get)
df
Out[155]: 
   one    Two
A   10  every
B   20   good
C   30    boy
D   40   does
E   50   fine
```

Comment: @Nitin it will loop via every single index look up the key to find the value in the dict

Comment: Sorry, I meant like why does the .get method make the code work, as opposed to just the dictionary

Comment: @Nitin base on pandas doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html, it only accpet mapper function not dict or Serise .

Comment: Weird. I hadn’t upvoted this. Well, problem solved.

Comment: doesnt seem necessary as of 2022. df.index.map(dict) works for me

Answer (score 16):

As of pandas version 0.23.x (released at May 15th, 2018) this problem is fixed:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__        # 0.23.4

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30, 'D': 40, 'E': 50}})
map_dict = {'A': 'every', 'B': 'good', 'C': 'boy', 'D': 'does', 'E': 'fine'}
df
#    one
# A   10
# B   20
# C   30
# D   40
# E   50
df.index.map(map_dict)
#        one
# every   10
# good    20
# boy     30
# does    40
# fine    50
```

From the [What's New page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html) for pandas 0.23.0 it says:

> Index.map() can now accept Series and dictionary input objects (GH12756, GH18482, GH18509).

For more information, check the help page of [Index.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative workaround to calling map:

```
df['two'] = pd.Series(map_dict)

df

   one    two
A   10  every
B   20   good
C   30    boy
D   40   does
E   50   fine
```

In any case, until the mapping issue gets resolved (per juanpa.arrivillaga's comment) you have to convert either the index or the dict-to-map to a pandas Series.

Answer (score 4):

A shorter alternative --with no explicit call to `to_series` or `pd.Series`:

```
df['two'] = df.rename(map_dict).index
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` (a python keyword) is apparently being used as a method of `df.index`

Because this has its own internal demands, passing it an argument which has no `__call__` method is not allowed.

`lambda` and functions are callable, a simple test:

```
def foo():
    pass
if foo.__call__:
    print True
# Prints True

bar = lambda x: x+1
if bar.__call__:
    print True
# Prints True

print {'1':'one'}.__call__
# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__call__'
```

Comment: `map` isn't being "overridden". `map` is a function, not a method, so there is nothing to override.