# Summing specific columns based on a mapping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a series which contains a mapping:

```
serm = pd.Series(
data={'ARD1': 53, 'BUL1': 37, 
'BUL2': 37, 'BSR1': 49, 'BTR1': 53, 'CR1': 53,
'CRR1': 53, 'CRE3': 53,'TAB1': 52, 'NEP1': 42, 'HAL1': 42})
```

which maps the asset id (the index) to an area (the value).
I have the the following dataframe where `serm` index is the columns names.

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data={'ARD1': {0: 4.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 2.0},
'BUL1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
'BUL2': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
'BSR1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
'BTR1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
'CR1': {0: 15.0, 1: 13.0, 2: 13.0, 3: 11.0, 4: 13.0},
'CRR1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
'CRE3': {0: 8.0, 1: 10.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 10.0, 4: 11.0},
'TAB1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
'NEP1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
'HAL1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}})
```

I would like to sum the columns of `data` that fall in the same area, according to the mapping of `serm`. How can I achieve this (the more `pandanoic` the better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) per columns and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = data.groupby(data.columns.map(serm.get), axis=1).sum()
print (df)
    37   42   49   52    53
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  27.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  25.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  24.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  24.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  26.0
```

Or assign columns back and use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
data.columns = data.columns.map(serm.get)
df = data.sum(level=0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Would you mind explaining what `get` does? I couldn't find a good doc on it. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @Ali You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43356704/2901002), but if use last version of pandas get should be omit.