# Pandas how to mutate a series based on index values and keep other series values

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the below df and dictionary

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

a = list(product((1,2,3),('A','B','C')))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns= ['num', 'letter']).set_index('letter')

mapper = {'B' : 21, 'A': 20}

df

   num
A   1
B   1
C   1
A   2
B   2
C   2
A   3
B   3
C   3
```

My objective is to replace `num` values based on `mapper` else keep `num` values. Desired outcome below:

```
    num     
A   20
B   21
C   1
A   20
B   21
C   2
A   20
B   21
C   3
```

Could this be achieved without looping over `mapper` keys and setting value for `num`?

Please note I'm trying to map only a few values of the index. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356704/map-dataframe-index-using-dictionary) also helpful.

Thank you in advance.

pandas 0.23.4

python 3.7.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map dataframe index using dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356704/map-dataframe-index-using-dictionary)

Comment: similar i agree, but does not explain how to keep `num` values. I was not aware of update method. Thanks @anky_91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the `mapper` dictionary to a `pd.Series()` and use [`df.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update the values:

```
df.update(pd.Series(mapper,name='num'))
#or df.num=df.index.to_series(name='num').map(mapper).fillna(df.num).astype(int)
print(df.astype(int))

        num
letter     
A        20
B        21
C         1
A        20
B        21
C         2
A        20
B        21
C         3
```